# Kmeans clustering using TENSORFLOW2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, spherical-kmeans

How could I convert a pandas database that contains 47 columns and 99999 lines into a tensors in
 Tensorflow 2? is the Kmeans algorithm already implemented under TF 2? because the command `tf.contrib.factorization.KMeans` does not work under TF2 since `tf.contrib` no longer exists on the second API Tensorflow

1. List item

Answer (score 0):

I got my TF2 example working with KMeans implementation from here [`tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.KMeans`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/experimental/KMeans?hl=en#example)

**Note:** As of Nov 7, 2019 the code example has a problem. Change `tf.estimator.experimental.KMeans` to `tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.KMeans`

---

Also for anyone looking for TF 2 contrib, there's a quote on the r1.15 [`tf.contrib`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib) page:

> **Warning:** The tf.contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
>   Many of its submodules have been integrated into TensorFlow core, or
>   spun-off into other projects like tensorflow_io, or tensorflow_addons.
>   For instructions on how to upgrade see the Migration guide.